# How to install finger print driver on lenovo X1 carbon on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, lenovo, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I need to  install the finger print driver of my X1 carbon 5th gen on Ubuntu 16.04. Where can I find drivers for Linux distributions?

Here are the outputs of `lspci`

```
kasun@kasun-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-5th:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5904 (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d12 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d18 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d4e (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM (rev 21)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 24fd (rev 88)
05:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a804
kasun@kasun-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-5th:~$
```

and the `lsusb` output

```
kasun@kasun-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-5th:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 138a:0097 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5682 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
kasun@kasun-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-5th:~$
```

Answer (score 12):

The *138a:0097 Validity Sensors, Inc.* is still being "reverse engineered" and not supported yet by the easy to install `fingerprint` or others.

The following is a WIP (Work In Progress) by Nikita Mikhailov:

1. `sudo apt install git libusb-1.0-0-dev libxv-dev`
2. `git clone https://github.com/nmikhailov/Validity90.git`
3. `cd Validity90/libfprint`
4. `./configure`
5. `make`
6. `make check`
7. `sudo make install`

Additional information and discussions:

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Validity-Fingerprint-Reader-Linux/td-p/3352145

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94536

Comment: Hi all, did anyone got it working with X1 Carbon?

Comment: doesn't work for my X1 Yoga using Bus 001 Device 004: ID 138a:0090 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
 too

Comment: actually https://github.com/hrenod/libfprint worked for me on the ThinkPad X1 Yoga!

Comment: The ticket seems to have moved here now https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/issues/54 but it looks like they need somebody to verify it's working for 138a:0097. I have one of those on my Lenovo P51, but I don't know how to install the fix to test it. I'm currently waiting for my registration at their GitLab site to be confirmed, so I can ask. But in the meantime, can anybody here tell me how?

Answer (score 6):

You may try to use the work by @uunicorn (https://github.com/uunicorn/python-validity). It works for my Ubuntu 20.04.1.

1. `$ sudo apt remove fprintd`
2. `$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:uunicorn/open-fprintd`
3. `$ sudo apt-get update`
4. `$ sudo apt install open-fprintd fprintd-clients python3-validity`
5. `$ fprintd-enroll`

If the last command prompt an error `list_devices failed:`, do

```
sudo systemctl status python3-validity
```

to check the status of the service and try to reset the device: (require closing all processes occupying the device, e.g. ̍Users̍ settings/fingerprint enrolling on Ubuntu 20.04.1)

1. `sudo systemctl stop python3-validity`
2. `sudo validity-sensors-firmware`
3. `sudo python3 /usr/share/python-validity/playground/factory-reset.py`
4. `sudo systemctl start python3-validity`
5. `fprintd-enroll`

You should be able to enroll your fingerprints on the command line.
Now if you are using Ubuntu 20, try to go to the `Users` settings and there should be
an option `Fingerprint Login` under `Authentication & Login`.

(You may have to first enable fingerprint authentication in `pam-auth-update`: do

1. `sudo pam-auth-update`
2. Select the line `Fingerprint authentication`, press spacebar to enable
3. Select `Ok` to confirm the changes)

Answer (score 2):

Running Ubuntu 20.04 on 7th Gen X1 Carbon

An article posted here http://www.adamisrael.com/project/ubuntu-on-x1/ made me aware of the

```
fwupdmgr
```

After running

```
fwupdmgr get-updates
```

I could see that the driver for the fingerprint reader wasn't installed.  In Adam's article he stated that the update manager didn't work but it is a few months old now.

Just run

```
fwupdmgr update
```

and it will install the necessary driver.

TLDR;

Run

```
fwupdmgr update
```

Comment: tried this but i'm not `fprint-list` is not seeing my device :(

Answer (score 1):

The only current software for the 138a:0097 is https://github.com/nmikhailov/Validity90/tree/master/prototype however there is no driver as of yet, so the WIP that krispy mentioned will not work to unlock your computer. There is just a prototype that can only scan and check the internal database, there is still no way to add fingerprints outside of Windows.

To further support development I suggest you follow the instructions at https://github.com/nmikhailov/Validity90/blob/master/prototype/README.md and create a new issue on GitHub with the output of the prototype.

```
sudo apt-get install make gcc libgcrypt-dev libglib2.0-dev libnss3-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev libssl-dev libpng-dev libgnutls28-dev
make
./prototype
```

And copy the output to https://github.com/nmikhailov/Validity90/issues/new with the title "Prototype output for Thinkpad X1 Carbon 5th Generation (138a:0097)"